# How would you say, "Don't let price interfere with your happiness" in Cantonese?

Tags: translation, cantonese, hong-kong

How would you say, "Don't let price interfere with your happiness" in Cantonese?

After asking a few Cantonese speakers, there were still no conclusive answers but a few suggestions:

1)冇俾價錢影響你快樂

2)冇俾價錢影響你選擇

3)冇俾價錢影響你情緒

None of these seem right. What's the right way to say this?

The context: we were eating dinner with a friend, and she wanted to order something at the restaurant, but it cost $1 more than normal. Even though she really was craving the dish, she chose something cheaper in order to save $1.

Comment: Instead of asking Cantonese speakers to translate this rather strained English slogan, why not ask them to suggest a better sounding slogan you could use?

Comment: I feel the Cantonese translations you listed have literally expressed the meaning, and they are "right" to my understanding of your original sentence, though they don't sound idiomatic enough. So, please explain what this sentence suggests in detail, I guess maybe that's something like "物輕情意重"?

Comment: Can you state under what circumstance that the phase is being used?

Comment: Your Cantonese translations are off. "冇" indicates the past: did not let the price .... Since your English is in the imperative, the translation should be "唔好。。。“ I also have queries as to what the speaker means.

Comment: Thanks @monalisa! Will remember this. All, the context has been provided now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 唔好俾價錢影響你嘅樂趣
2) 唔好俾價錢減低你嘅樂趣

answer 1) should be correct, but I listed answer 2) because it is more common to refer "`interfere with happiness`" with its meaning of actually "`reducing the happiness`" in cantonese

Answer (score 4):

"咪俾個價錢掃你興啦!"

- 咪 = 唔好 = Don't
- 俾 = allow / let
- "個" .... It sounds more natural with this quantifier
- 價錢 = price
- 掃你興 ~= 減低你嘅樂趣 ~= 影響你嘅樂趣 = interfere with your happiness
- "啦" .... It sounds more natural with this interjection